# Boostrap Pagination + VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, bootstrap-vue

I am using [bootstrap pagination](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination).

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

I have no idea how to accomplish that, this is my code:

```
<b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="notices.length" :per-page="perPage" hide-goto-end-buttons limit="2" ellipsis-text="of">
  <template v-slot:prev-text><IconPaginationPrev /></template> <!--using a different icon here-->
  <template v-slot:next-text><IconPaginationNext /></template> <!--using a different icon here-->
</b-pagination>
```

This is how it looks on my end:

[image]

How can I add that "of" word then the last page will always be there?

Thanks and hoping for help to arrive!

Answer (score 0):

The native bootstrap is providing such options. Alternatively, you can design a simple pager like the one you need and map its page navigation events to the table data.